# throwing c++ exception from android native code hangs thread

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

It seems that when I throw an exception from outside of a JNICALL function, any thrown exceptions will hang the thread.

That is, if I throw an exception directly inside a JNICALL function (java native function), it can be caught properly. If it's thrown from a function or method that the JNICALL function calls, even just once call deep, it will hang the thread.

I am confused and I can't find any references to anyone else having this issue.

My project is using the latest stable ndk, APP_STL is set to c++_shared, and the language std is set to gnuc++11.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you catching and dealing with all C++ exceptions before returning from C++ to Java?

Comment: This behaviour is expected. You must handle the exception that the java side is throwing in C++ by calling describe. Otherwise the JVM will wait infinitely iirc.

Comment: I am catching the C++ exceptions, or attempting to, before I hand them back to java via env->ThrowNew. the code flow just stops at the throw statement, and never returns or dies.

Comment: I just tried switching to gnustl_shared from c++_shared, and instead of hanging, its crashing with a stack corruption error (I have the sanitizer enabled) when throw is called. Trying to track that down now.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear it might be a conflict with AddressSanitizer. Once I uninstalled it from the phone and disabled asan compiler flags, it's now working.